# Creating a PayPal Subscription Button in Sandbox mode

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to setup a sandbox for PayPal Smart Buttons to test before I release to production.

When I go to [PayPal Subscriptions](https://www.paypal.com/billing/overview), I select my plan and click 'Copy Code'. The result is:

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=XXX&vault=true" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
      ....
      createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.subscription.create({
          'plan_id': 'P-YYYY'
        });
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        alert(data.subscriptionID);
      }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

Is there a way to enable sandbox for logging in? I see that I can create sandbox accounts at [Developer Accounts](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/) page but the sandbox accounts created there do not work (I mean how is it supposed to know I am in 'sandbox mode'?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sandbox and live environments are completely separate.

Using a sandbox business account, log into the www.sandbox.paypal.com environment, and then you can go to:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/overview (same as your link, but with '**sandbox.**' in the URL.

Create sandbox plans there. These sandbox subscriptions can be tested with sandbox personal accounts.